# Spring boot + Server monitoring

Tags: spring, monitoring

I have requirement to monitor some particular java processes on that server and display on web with color (red or green). Is there any such lib in spring world?
let's say

| Process Name | Status |
| --- | --- |
| process1 | RED |
| process2 | GREEN |

I don't want to use any monitoring toll such as grafan, promotheus, appdynamics, geneos..

Answer (score 0):

if your status red mean process is stop, green mean process is running,there 2 ways.

- if you are using spring cloud like eureka, it supplys some apis
- each process just supply a simple request. if the process is running, the request will return success, if not, the request may be 404...

Comment: i usually use the second way to test  weather my process is deploy success or not.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.  yes, RED means process is down, and GREEN means process is UP, but these all are internal java processes, no api's around it.  So Eurekha Cloud is not best fit for my requirement.